# How do I copy a body from one DOCX file to another using .NET and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I'm responsible for writing a script that updates a batch of .DOT into .PDF files.  So far, I've converted the DOT files into DOCX files and pasted some necessary bookmarks.  I'm currently trying to add the new template's header and footer, but that's proving somewhat troublesome.

I have a DOCX template file with the correct header/footer and no body.  My current plan is to extract the body from the target file and paste it into the template's initially-blank body.  This will be done for each document.

So far, all efforts to copy the body either pastes the last line of the target DOCX file or overwrites the template's header/footer.  I've done this by copy/pasting the entire range and section-by-section.  Do you know how to paste only the body of the target DOCX file into the body of (or simply as) the template DOCX file?

I would also like to retain the formatting of each document: same font-family, font-size, tables, etc.

Comment: I've also tried copying the HeaderFoot elements from the template DOCX file into the target DOCX file, but that never worked out either.  The image in the header would lose its top half (despite still occupying the space), and the footer lost its text formatting.  This is all despite pasting headers with their source formatting.  Do you know of any other tools that may help?

Comment: Can't guarantee a result, but probably worth trying to use the FormattedText member of Word's Range object if copy/paste with formatting isn't doing what you want.